# How do I provide a PCB manufacturer with via type information (such as "Filling and Capping") from Altium Designer?

Tags: pcb, pcb-design, altium, pcb-fabrication, via

I have a PCB design in Altium with all of the IPC 4761 Via Types specified on each via. What are the industry standard ways to provide this information to the manufacturer?

I normally export my designs to Gerber but I do not believe the via type information is included in Gerber files.

Comment: In my case, and for large quantities, we selected the via types directly with the manufacturer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What's generally done (e.g. by myself) is to put such information in a proper fabrication drawing (PDF). I have a dedicated section in my fab drawing for "Special Requirements" that has an option "Via Filling". It might say something like this: "IPC-4761 Type VII for all 0.3mm drill vias".

I additionally generate a single gerber file "Via_Filling.gbr" that has a dot (dot diameter = via hole diameter) for every via that needs to be filled. The gerber file might be optional and may depend on the capabilities of your ECAD tool. I don't know about Altium. But with the tool I'm using it's really easy to generate such a gerber file.

If you already know who is manufacturing the board, it's always a good idea to talk to your fabricator directly. Of course, the goal should be to create PCB production data that is as fabricator-agnostic as possible.